# Extremal graph without cycle length $k$ or longer.

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

When $k\geq 3$, denote $\mathcal{C}_{k}=\left\{C_{n}\mid n\geq k\right\}$ the family of cycles of graph.

I am trying to find ${\rm{ex}}\left(n;\mathcal{C}_{k}\right)$ and ${\rm{EX}}\left(n;\mathcal{C}_{k}\right)$. The following is my attempt:

I have known that the extremal graph forbidden the path $P_{k+1}$ ($k+1$ vertices.) : $${\rm{EX}}\left(n;P_{k+1}\right)=\left\{G_{n,k},G_{n,k,\ell}\right\}.$$

Write $n=kq+r$ with $0\leq r<k$, $G_{n,k}=qK_{k}\cup K_{r}$. Further, if $k\geq 3$ is an odd, $r=\left(k\pm 1\right)/2$, and $0\leq\ell <q$, $G_{n,k,\ell}=\ell K_{k}\cup\left(K_{\left(k-1\right)/2}+\overline{K_{n-k\ell -\left(k-1\right)/2}}\right)$.

Since we want to avoid the cycle of length larger than $k-1$, it seems that when removing a vertex, the new graph must avoid $P_{k-1}$. If we pick any $G\in{\rm{EX}}\left(n-1;P_{k-1}\right)$, adding a new vertex into $G$ adjacent to all other vertices gives a new graph which avoid all cycle with length larger than $k-1$. This is a possible graph for the reason that when adding any other edges, it must form a $P_{k-1}$ in the original graph $G$ and induce a cycle of length $k$. Thus, we have ${\rm{ex}}\left(n;\mathcal{C}_{k}\right)\geq {\rm{ex}}\left(n-1;P_{k-1}\right)+n-1$.

But I cannot go further to find explitity number of ${\rm{ex}}\left(n;\mathcal{C}_{k}\right)$, not to mention ${\rm{EX}}\left(n;\mathcal{C}_{k}\right)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's one way to get an upper bound on $\text{ex}(n;\mathcal{C}_k)$. By a ``longest path'' argument, it's not difficult to show that if $\delta(G)\geq k$, then $G$ has a cycle of length at least $k+1$. Now, if $G$ has average degree $d$, we can always find a subgraph of $G$ with minimum degree at least $d/2$, so if $G$ has no member of $\mathcal{C}_k$, then $d/2<k-1$. In other words, $\text{ex}(n;\mathcal{C}_k)<(k-1)n$.

Comment: Also, if $G$ does not have a cycle of length $3$ or longer, then $G$ must be acyclic, so $\text{ex}(G,\mathcal{C}_3)=n-1$. If $G$ does not have a cycle of length $4$ or longer, then $G$ must be a ``triangle forest'' (a collection of edges and triangles so that if you remove any one edge from each triangle, you get a forest), so $\text{ex}(G,\mathcal{C}_4)\approx{3\over 2}n$. From this, it seems reasonable to conjecture that $\text{ex}(G,\mathcal{C}_k)\approx{k-1\over 2}n$. The lower bound is true since you can take ${n-1\over k-2}$ copies of $K_{k-1}$ which all share a vertex.